# I tried to take user input for a 2d array in c but for 2X3 matrix it only take 2 input

Tags: c

Trying to declare a two-dimensional matrix and assign values to it. But program takes only 2 input and then exits.

```
        int m, n;
        int arr[m][n];
        printf("enter the numbers of row:");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        printf("enter the numbers of column:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("your matrix is %d X %d\n"); 
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<3;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

it only takes 2 output from user.
EDIT: converted image to code

**Output:**

```
enter number of rows:2    
enter number of columns:3    
your matrix is: 2 X 3    
1    
2
```

Comment: Please do not post screen shots - post the code

Answer (score 2):

```
int m, n;
int arr[m][n];
```

You are creating an 2d array from uninitialized values of m and n which will give undefined behaviour. Before creating 2d array initialize values of m and n.

```
int m,n;
printf("Enter the numbers of row:");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("Enter number of column:");
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[m][n]  //now m and n have a defined value
```

Now in for loop, it look like you are using fixed number of rows and column which takes away the need of m and n.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: now it's take only one input

Comment: You have to use '&' operator to pass address of variable in scanf("%d", &arr[m][n]);  it should work then.